# Moving cells to an empty range above them

Tags: google-apps-script

In my apps script, I have a range that I divided in a way that there are 4 values in each section. It looks like this:

[image: Range]

Now, let's say someone removes all the 4 values from the second section so the range looks like this:

[image: Range]

What my desired effect is that when someone removes all the values from a section, all the values from under the empty section would come up, so that the end result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Note that the values are completely random.

Comment: Move cell values or delete rows?

Comment: Could you share an example sheet? try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way

Comment: You can also sort the range

Answer (score 1):

#### Moving empty cells to bottom

```
function specialsort() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const rg = sh.getRange("A2:A21");
  const vs = rg.getDisplayValues();
  vs.sort((a,b) => {
    if(a[0] && b[0]) {
      return 0;
    } else if( a[0] && !b[0]) {
      return -1;
    } else if(!a[0] && b[0]) {
      return 1;
    } 
  })
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs))
  rg.setValues(vs)
}
```